# Sum values in specific rows and place value in first column of that row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to sum values in the row that contains 'BB' and place that value in first column of that row.

**Data**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421
AA  8.0  4.8  3.1  5.3
BB  0.6  0.7  0.3  0.9
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421
AA  8.0  4.8  3.1  5.3
BB  2.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

**Doing**

```
 df.loc[df['ID'] == BB, 'Q121','Q221','Q321','Q421'].sum()
```

Not sure how to then place this value in the first column

I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with a boolean mask to assign the new values :

```
mask = df['ID'].eq('BB')
cols = df.columns.difference(['ID'])
update = [df.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)]

df.loc[mask, cols] = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols, update)), index=df.index)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

**Note** : [**`pandas.DataFrame.sum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) is used to calculate the sum over the `axis=1 (columns)`.

###### # Output :

```
print(df)

   ID  Q121  Q221  Q321  Q421
0  AA   8.0   4.8   3.1   5.3
1  BB   2.5   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, where in the code does it define where the 2.5  goes? I will read documentation